# Change what's displayed in a Django template using the Python variables

Tags: python, html, django, tabs

I have recently started working on some software that has been written in Python/ Django, and I am looking to change what information is displayed on one of the webpages.

The page currently displays a number of tabs, with different information from the database displayed on each tab. The tabs are titled: Overview, Budget, Works, & Items.

On the Items tab, there are four columns: Items, Initial Sum, Latest Sum, & Notes.

There are `view`s in the Python code that are used to set up what's displayed on each tab, and the one for the `Items` tab that I want to change is defined with:

```
def report_ccis(request, project_id):
    """ CCI items styled for pdf """
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    budget = get_current_budget(project_id)

    cci_total_exc = budget.cci_total_exc_vat_final
    cci_grouped_items = budget.cci_items.all().order_by('project_room', 'name')

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'cci_total_exc': cci_total_exc,
        'cci_grouped_items': cci_grouped_items,
        'webview': 1,
    }

    try: context['current_budget'] = project.budget_versions.get(current_marker=1) #For option name/date on top of pdfs
    except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass

    if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':
        """ Render post deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
        context['active_tab'] = '4'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    else:
        """ Render pre deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
        context['active_tab'] = '5'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

I want to remove the 'Latest Sum' column from this tab in the browser, but I'm not sure how to stop the `view` that's displaying the 'Items' tab from getting/ displaying that information on the tab...

The HTML files that are being populated with by this `view` have code similar to the following:

```
{% extends "pdf2_base.html" %}
{% block web_content %}

{% block content_payment_schedule %}
{% endblock content_payment_schedule %}

{% block content_overview %}
{% endblock content_overview %}

{% block content_ccis %}
    {{block.super}}
{% endblock content_ccis %}

{% block agreed_variations %}
{% endblock agreed_variations %}

{% block agreed_variations_client %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_client %}

{% block agreed_variations_construction %}
{% endblock agreed_variations_construction %}

{% block unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock unagreed_variations %}
{% endblock web_content %}
```

As I understand, the HTML used to render the webpages in the browser is generated by the Python variables in the .html file- this is the part that is quite new to me... if it was just plain HTML, I would know how to locate the information that I want to remove from the page, but I can't find where it's being displayed in the HTML files here... or how it's being retrieved by the Python `view`...

If I 'inspect' the part of the page that I want to remove in the browser, it shows that it is in following structure:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="wrapper">
        ...
            <div class="content">
                <div class="tabbed m-r-lg text-sm">
                    ...
                    <pdf:nexttemplate name="nofooter">
                        <pdf:nextpage>
                            ...
                            <pdf:nextpage>
                                <pdf:nextpage>
                                    <table class="pdf-report left">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                ...
                                                <th>Latest Sum (£)</th> == $0
                                                ...
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                ...
                            </pdf:nextpage>
                        </pdf:nextpage>
                    </pdf:nexttemplate>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

As is shown by the the HTML, the content that I want to change is displayed in a PDF embedded within the webpage, but obviously, I need to change it via the Python- I'm just not sure how I would do this, as I can't see anything in the Python that references the 'latest sum' field that I want to remove...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

The child template for the web page is:

```
{% extends "costing/reports_tabbed.html" %}
{% load staticfiles utilities %}

{% block title2 %}
    | Pre-deposit reports
{% endblock title2 %}

{% block page_title %}
    <a id="topbar-shortcuts" data-view-url="{% url 'hub:open_sidebar' %}?app={{app.name}}&p={{project.id}}&po=1">
        <span class="m-l-md">Reports</span> <img class="icon open text-sm m-l-md" src="{% static 'img/down-lt.png' %}" >
    </a>
    <div id="topbar-results" class="{{app.color}}" style="display:none;"></div>
{% endblock page_title %}


{% block tabs %}
    {% with 'Overview, budget, works, items'|listify as tabs %}
        {% for tab_name in tabs %}
            {% with forloop.counter as tab %}
                {% if not tab == active_tab|add:0 %}<a class="tab" href="{% url 'costing:report_tabbed' project.id %}?tab={{tab}}">{% else %}<a class="active tab">{% endif %}{{tab_name}}</a>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock tabs %}
```

The column I want to remove is displayed on the `items` tab, but I can't see anything in the view/ HTML that specifies what is displayed on each tab...

Comment: That is not the right template file; that is the base that contains the blocks to be extended by child templates. Your view is calling the specific templates, those are where you should be looking. (Note however that rendering one template to a string to be inserted into another template is a very odd thing to do.)

Comment: Apologies- I'm still getting to grips with how Python/ Django works! I'll add the child template now.

Comment: I've added in what is hopefully the correct template file.

Comment: In the Base template I don't see the blocks - tittle2, page_title, tabs. Probably you again uploaded not correct templates. Also as a possibility - part of template can be included by JS. Please, change the question and remove not important code.

Comment: Apologies- I've added the template where `title2`, `page_title` & `tabs` are defined. It seems that it's the `for` loop in the `tabs` block that is getting all of the columns & data displayed in the table- is there a way to prevent it from getting/ displaying a specific column? This only appears to be looking at the tabs, not the content of the tabs... I think I possibly want to look at the call to `costing:report_tabbed` here?